# How to have a curved edge triangle

Tags: css

I wanted a curved edge triangle in css3.Is it possible to get it in css3 ?
My code below has a normal triangle...

http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/

```
#left-triangle {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-right: 100px solid orange;
   border-top: 50px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

I wanted like this..
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

**CSS**

```
.arrow{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.arrow:after{
    content:'';
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-70px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dVbJr/4/